# How can I query for documents with a given undefined field in Solr?

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I cannot get how to query my index for all the documents not having the optional field named "adm4".

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kludgy**: Make sure the `adm4` field is indexed and give it a default value in your schema.xml file. Then querying for that default value will return all documents that didn't get a "real" value for `adm4` at index time. For example, if `adm4` is an integer and 0 is not a meaningful value...

```
<field name="adm4" type="int" default="0" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**Much Better**: Add `-adm4:[* TO *]` to your query per [SolrQuerySyntax docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax). I found this after my first answer, but I'm editing rather than replacing or your comment wouldn't make sense.  :)

EDIT: After more testing (Solr 4.3), it seems the range is unneeded and `-adm4:*` yields the same result.

Comment: it sounds more like a workaround then an actual solution. Is there actually not a way to do it in case a default value is not desired?

Comment: Very true. I did some more research and found a pure query option. Answer is edited to include this option.

Comment: I've tested this with numeric and string fields and it works in both cases. Just be sure the word `TO` in the range is all-caps.